# Finding fields to update based on combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to be able to display in my results who needs updates.  I have a temp table I created that looks like this. The rule is per ID they cannot have more than 1 MASTER = 1.  They must have FULLTIME = 1 on that record and all other records will be FULLTIME = 0 and PARTTIME = 1.  This is quite difficult because you have to compare across multiple IDs.

I've tried combinations using maxes, count distinct, subqueries, etc.  No luck getting it done.  I've even tried to do some manipulation in Excel but it's totally confusing to me.

```
select distinct
x.ID,
COUNT(x.ID) AS ID_Count
from #FT0PT1M1Version2 as x
join (

select 
ID, NAME, MASTER, FULLTIME, PARTTIME 
from #FT0PT1M1Version2
WHERE E = 'P'
GROUP BY 
ID, NAME, MASTER, FULLTIME, PARTTIME 
HAVING COUNT(ID) = '1'

) as y
    on x.ID = y.ID   
    WHERE 
    x.PARTTIME = '1' and
    x.MASTER = '1'

    group by x.ID
    HAVING COUNT(x.ID) = '1'
    order by 1
```

Temp Table

```
ID  NAME            MASTER  FULLTIME    PARTTIME
1   JAMES JONES     0       1              0
1   JAMES JONES     1       0              1
1   JAMES JONES     0       0              1
2   MICHEAL JORDAN  1       1              0
2   MICHEAL JORDAN  0       0              1
2   MICHEAL JORDAN  0       0              1
3   JOHN DOE        1       1              0
3   JOHN DOE        0       0              1
```

Expected Results

```
ID  NAME            MASTER  FULLTIME  PARTTIME  UPDATE
1   JAMES JONES     0       1         0         Y
1   JAMES JONES     1       0         1         Y
1   JAMES JONES     0       0         1         N
2   MICHEAL JORDAN  1       1         0         N
2   MICHEAL JORDAN  0       0         1         N
2   MICHEAL JORDAN  0       0         1         N
3   JOHN DOE        1       1         0         N
3   JOHN DOE        1       0         1         Y
```

Comment: rule is if master = 1 then fulltime also = 1, except parttime? is't right? i don't really get the rule. can u elaborate the rule?

Comment: Yes if any id has a master then its fulltime=1 and parttime =0 but if id's master is 0 then it should have parttime raised as 1 and fulltime becomes 0

Comment: You'll have to sharpen the rules in my opinion. **Rule 1:** (MASTER,FULLTIME,PARTTIME) not in ((0,0,1),(1,1,0), (1,1,1)) => UPDATE=Y. **Rule 2:** Too many masters. Then what? Elect one row of them to be the real master? Which? Or elect one row new master including those that are not master yet? Which again? Or just mark all master rules with UPDATE=Y? Or even all rows? **Rule 3:** No master. Pick one row? Which? Or mark all rows UPDATE=Y?

Comment: For what DBMS are you asking this for? SQL questions should always be tagged with the DBMS used (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try below query  but I would prefer to put a check constraint on columns like check if master=1 then update ='Y' something like that.

```
SELECT ID, NAME, 
       CASE 
           WHEN (MASTER=1 AND FULLTIME=1 And PARTTIME=0) 
                 OR (MASTER=0 AND FULLTIME=0 And PARTTIME=1) 
             Then 'N' 
          ELSE 'Y' 
       END as "Update"
from table group by ID, NAME, Update 
Having sum(Master) = 1;
```

Comment: well, this solution can solve that problem. With some modification, without using `group by` and `having`, it would produce the result like expected.

Comment: One more thing.  How would get those lines where only ID exists?  For example, Jane Doe only has one ID and ID2 combination?